# Which was the first movie remake?

Tags: first-appearance

I want to know Which was the first movie remake in the history of movies?
I do not mean reboot. I mean remake i.e. with same story (mostly).

Comment: Depends what you mean by "remake".  From what I've read of the history of cinema, early duplication equipment was hard on the original films, so early makers of film would film their actors, run off as many prints as they could before the quality got too bad, sell those, and once they were all sold (if they were popular) call back the actors, have them do the same skit again, and run off another bunch of copies.

Comment: I think films based on the same novel are no remake? If you would accept it as a remake, then [A Christmas Carol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptations_of_A_Christmas_Carol#Film) may be one of the earliest remakes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps the earliest remake is The Squaw Man:

[The Squaw Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0004635/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (1914), followed by [The Squaw Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0009650/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3) (1918), asserting the first full-length feature remake was in 1918.

These films--and even the subsequent [The Squaw Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0022428/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2) (1931)--were filmed by Cecil B. DeMille.

From Wikipedia:

> The Squaw Man went on to become the only movie successfully filmed
>   three times by the same director/producer, DeMille. He did a silent
>   remake in 1918, and a talkie version in 1931.

Answer (score 6):

I got one from 1904. French movie "Personal" got copied by Edison in the same year: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0000492/

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was An Excursion to the Moon, made in 1908, it was a remake, near shot by shot, of the famous A Trip To The Moon